# How to return HttpResponse with token generated in tiers microservice

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, jwt, microservices

UP!
EDIT : 
maybe i'm not clear enough in my question : it seems the HttpResponse i have in my controller of my API web controller doesn't contain the cookie or the Jwt token i put in it in my MS-Authentication. I think the problem could be in the method i declare in proxy interface. What kind of return i need to get back my response updated ?

I have one micro-service "Authentication", one gateway with Zuul and one Api web.

I implement jwt token security with spring boot security.

When my user try to login from api web, username and password are send to MS-Authentication (Zuul is configure to let anyone call this MS) and after verify user is in database, it generate a token.

My problem is i can't get back the response with token inside (or cookie, i try to put the token in a cookie and add cookie in response).

It's my first project with spring boot and micro-services!

When i don't use Api and make test with postmann, token is well return in response !

here is my code:
LoginController in Api-web

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private final BookProxy bookProxy;

    @Autowired
    public LoginController(BookProxy bookProxy) {
        this.bookProxy = bookProxy;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginForm(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("user",new UserBean());

        return "login";

    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String doLogin(@ModelAttribute UserBean user){

        bookProxy.authenticateClient(user);

        return "Home";
    }   
}
```

Proxy in Api-web

```
@FeignClient(name = "zuul-server", url = "localhost:8762") 
public interface Proxy {

    /* Login */
    @PostMapping("/auth/login")
    void authenticateClient(@RequestBody UserBean user);
}
```

SecurityConfig in Zuul Gateway

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityTokenConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Roles
    private static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    private static final String EMPLOYEE = "EMPLOYEE";
    private static final String CLIENT = "CLIENT";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/book/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN,EMPLOYEE)
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig in MS-Authentication

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityCredentialsConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityCredentialsConfig(UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService) {
        this.userPrincipalDetailsService = userPrincipalDetailsService;
    }

    // Roles
    private static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    private static final String EMPLOYEE = "EMPLOYEE";
    private static final String CLIENT = "CLIENT";


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth){
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()         
                .addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/auth/Login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/book/consult/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN,EMPLOYEE)
                .antMatchers("/book/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN,EMPLOYEE)
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){

        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userPrincipalDetailsService);

        return daoAuthenticationProvider;

    }

}
```

Filter who Authenticate user ans generate token in MS-Authentication

```
public class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    // We use auth manager to validate the user credentials
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;


    JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        this.authManager = authManager;

        // By default, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter listens to "/login" path.
        // I use "/auth" path so i need to override the defaults.
        this.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(JwtConfig.URI, "POST"));
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        // Grab credentials and map them to login viewmodel
        LoginViewModel credentials = null;
        try {
            credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginViewModel.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        // Create login token
        assert credentials != null;
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                credentials.getUsername(),
                credentials.getPassword(),
                new ArrayList<>());

        // Return authenticate user
            return authManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    // Upon successful authentication, generate a token.
    // The 'auth' passed to successfulAuthentication() is the current authenticated user.
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // Grab principal
        UserPrincipal principal = (UserPrincipal) auth.getPrincipal();


        String token = JWT.create()
                //.withHeader(headerClaims)
                .withClaim("role","ROLE_" + principal.getRole())
                .withSubject(principal.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JwtConfig.EXPIRATION))
                .sign(HMAC512(JwtConfig.SECRET.getBytes()));

        // ADD COOKIES
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(JwtConfig.HEADER, token);
        cookie.setSecure(false);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setMaxAge(999999);
        cookie.setDomain("localhost");
        cookie.setPath("/");

        // Add token and cookie in response (try both)
        response.addHeader(JwtConfig.HEADER, JwtConfig.PREFIX + token);
        response.addCookie(cookie);

    }

}
```

Jwt config constants

```
public class JwtConfig {

    public static final String URI = "/auth/**";
    public static final String HEADER = "Authorization";
    public static final String PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    public static final int EXPIRATION = 24*60*60;
    public static final String SECRET = "JwtSecretKey";

}
```